# Removing <head> issues, I need guide/assistance

Tags: ruby, parsing, rubygems, html-parsing, nokogiri

So guys, i'm make a web parser it was good but i saw that some words inside `<head>` is screwing everything up (and `<strong>` in the body too). My code is [This one here before nokogiri](https://gist.github.com/MoscrowDev/a7ffefa222b84ac5063cbd8eb46b185a) but I'm new at ruby programming and just started to know about Nokogiri few hours ago.

I wish someone could help me make this work. I need to .read the URL, remove `<head>` and everything inside it and scan words over the rest of the page

PS: Is it possible bring JUST the body and read it? It would be easier
PSS: About `<strong>` tags, is it hard to remove it?

My exercise is count how many especific word are in the page, not source code, thats why i need to only grab the body and eliminate a tag

Really hope someone can help me >.<
Thnks guys!

Here is my actual failure code / The pure original is [here](https://gist.github.com/MoscrowDev/a7ffefa222b84ac5063cbd8eb46b185a)

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'cgi'
require 'nokogiri'



class Counter

    def initialize(url)
        @url = url
    end

    def decapitate

        Nokogiri::HTML(url)

        url.css('head').remove.to_s
    end

    def scan(word)
        url.scan(word)
    end



end

url, word = ARGV

puts "Found #{Counter.new(url).open.decapitate.scan(word).length} maches."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many mistakes there.

- `url` in `decapitate` is an undefined local variable. You need to use `@url`.
- `Nokogiri::HTML` expects either an `IO` object, or a string, not an URL. You probably wanted to use `open(@url)` to read the URL contents (I assume, given that you required `open-uri`
- `Nokogiri::HTML` returns a document, but you don't store this return value anywhere
- Consequently, `url` (or rather `@url`) would be a string, and strings don't have a `css` method; you want to apply `css` to the document instead
- `remove` will return the node that is removed; as the last thing in the method, that will be what is returned. Thus `decapitate` would return the text of the `head` node.
- At the end, `...decapitate.scan` will invoke the `String#scan` method, not the method you defined.

You can do what you want as follows:

```
def count(pattern, url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css('head').remove
  doc.text.scan(pattern).size
end
```

Comment: Using `@url` is probably better than passing in `url` twice to two different methods.

Comment: @tadman: Oh yeah, I probably wasn't clear. My solution at the bottom is instead of OP's, not a plug-in. It's easy enough to adapt it. If it was going into the class, then I'd grab, decapitate and textify in constructor, storing `@text` rather than `@url`, so that one can count multiple things on the same document...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, a stand-alone method.